# Can't access from another container by service name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vpn, docker-network

I am using a [VPN container](https://github.com/ilteoood/docker-surfshark) (Surfshark) container for another container, so that it can access the internet through the VPN

I have this config:

```
version: '3'
services:
  bot:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "1111:1111"
  chrome:
    image: browserless/chrome
    network_mode: service:surfshark
  surfshark:
    image: ilteoood/docker-surfshark
    container_name: surfshark
    environment:
      - SURFSHARK_USER=$SURFSHARK_USER
      - SURFSHARK_PASSWORD=$SURFSHARK_PASSWORD
      - SURFSHARK_COUNTRY=es
      - CONNECTION_TYPE=udp
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    restart: unless-stopped
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
```

I want to access the host 'chrome' from the 'bot' container using the service name, but it's not working. How can I fix this?
For example, I go inside the bot container and run `wget http://chrome` there, I get an error `wget: bad address 'chrome'`

Comment: how are trying to access it from the bot container. can you give more details about how you going about it.

Comment: Anything, for example trite: `wget http://chrome`

Comment: Also, what does it mean: it's not working"

Comment: Everything works if you remove `network_mode: service: surfshark`, but then chrome will not go through vpn